# Using the area element in derivation of geodesic

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, geodesics

In the derivation of the geodesic, one starts with the integral of the line element (arclength):

$$L(C)=\int_{\tau_1}^{\tau_2}d\tau\sqrt{g_{\mu \nu}\dot{x}^{\mu} \dot{x}^{\nu}}$$

The integrand is then substituted into the Euler-Lagrange equation, which simplifies to the geodesic equation.

My question is would it be possible to start with the area element instead of the line element, and thereby arrive at a surface area geodesic equation, which I guess would be an equation for the surface area of a given patch of manifold?

Comment: This is the Nambu Goto action, and there is a deep theory of minimal surfaces attached to it, because there is a harmonic parametrization.

Comment: Instead of using the area element, would it be possible to use Green's theorem?

Comment: More on Nambu-Goto action: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nambu+Goto

Answer (score 1):

A particle traces out a wordline, hence the action is proportional to the arc length,

$$S = \int \mathrm{d}s \, \sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}\dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu}$$

Varying the action, as you stated, gives rise to the Euler-Lagrange equations which are equivalent to the geodesic equations. If we considered an action proportional to area, we would be describing a string as it traces a wordsheet rather than a line. If we denote $\sigma^\alpha$ the collective intrinsic coordinates on the sheet, then the induced metric is simply given by,

$$\gamma_{\alpha \beta} = \frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial \sigma^\alpha}\frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial \sigma^\beta} g_{\mu\nu}$$

where $X^\mu$ denote the embedding functions, and $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the metric of the target space. Naively, we would then write the action as,

$$S = -T\int \mathrm{d}^2 \sigma \, \sqrt{-\det\gamma} = -T \int \mathrm{d}^2 \sigma \, \sqrt{(\dot{X} \cdot X')^2 -(\dot{X})^2 (X')^2}$$

with implicit contraction with the metric, primes denote differentiation with respect to $\sigma$, and dots represented with respect to $\tau$, as we chose $\sigma^\alpha = (\tau, \sigma)$. The constant $T$ has dimensions of tension; whilst unrelated to the question, in the Nambu-Goto action it is given by,

$$T=\frac{1}{2\pi \alpha'}$$

where $\alpha'$ is the universal Regge slope. The $m^2$ against $J$ plot for hadrons gives rise to a linear regression line, which has a gradient $\alpha'$, hence the name. Historically, string theory was first explored as a means to explain strong interactions, rather than quantum gravity.

---

[image]

**Source:** David Tong's lecture notes on string theory, at http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.

Answer (score 1):

This is somwhat outside my area, but Elie Cartan developed a form of differential geometry based on the area element rather than the line element. The main reference in French is [E. Cartan. *Les espaces métriques fondés sur la notion d’aire*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2705656839).
There is a relatively recent arxiv article in English [*The concept of orthogonality in Cartan's geometry based on the concept of area*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1005) that extends these ideas.
The abstract says

> In 1931 Elie Cartan constructed a geometry which was rarely considered. Cartan proposed a way to define an infinitesimal metric ds starting from a variational problem on hypersurfaces in an n-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$. This distance depends not only of the point $\text{m}\in\mathcal{M}$ but on the orientation of a hyperplane in the tangent space $T_{\text{m}}\mathcal{M}$. His first step is a natural definition of the orthogonal direction to such tangent hyperplane. In this paper we extend it, starting form considerations from the calculus of variations.